# Problem when mixing TabNavigator and StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have 2 Stacks in a TabNavigator. The structure is as below

StackA

- Screen A

- Screen A1

- Screen A2

StackB

- Screen B

- Screen B1

- Screen B2

TabNavigator

- StackA

- StackB

Now, in screen A, I want to navigate to screen B1. I just use navigate('Screen B1'), the navigating looks successfully.
But when I click back button (I my god) I'm on StackB which is showing screen B.

I really expect seeing screen A in this case.

Comment: which version of React Navigation do you use?

Comment: @Majidlotfinia, I'm using "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"

Comment: Could you change `initialRouteName` ? `initialRouteName : Screen B1` in StackB

Comment: @hongdevelop, absolutely not, because root screen of StackB is B. For StackB, screen B must be presented first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you will have to create a custom `backButton` that let's your screen know where you navigated from. An example would be:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB1', {lastScreen:"ScreenA1"})   //navigating from stack to other stack with param
```

Then, the `backButton` would check about the `lastScreen` variable and see if it's defined.

```
<BackButton onPress={({navigation})=>{
    let lastScreen=navigation.state.params.lastScreen
    if (lastScreen) return navigation.navigate(lastScreen)
    else navigation.pop(1)
    }
}
```

As i dont know how your code looks like i wrote a general situation, but you can change it however you need.

Comment: does navigation.navigate(lastScreen) really back to the previous screen? Or it only navigate to the screen "lastScreen"?

Comment: It navigates to the real last screen

Comment: I've tried. It renders view again instead of really back to previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `Stack A` and `Stack B` are in different stacks. The other stack navigators are within the `tab navigator`, so they can be moved, but the back button, which is the default stack navigator command, is not moved where you want them to be. Because the initial screen of your `stack B` is `screen B`, you will see `screen B1` on top of it after the stack of `screen B` is stacked. If you want to go where you want to go, press the Back button and go to the desired screen

```js
// B1 Screen Back button
navigate('Screen A') 

// OR If you want Screen A to be rendered again,
push('Screen A')
```